# Two consecutive error while drawing a bit pattern

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, math, random

I am trying to draw a bit stream with the code block below:

But unfortunately Python throws two errors which are:

```
C:\Users\bahadir.yalin\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py:171: VisibleDeprecationWarning: Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.
  return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order, subok=True)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

and

```
return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

How can I get rid of the problem? Can someone help me please?
Thank you for your time..

```
import random as rand
import numpy as np
import math as m
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = [round(rand.randint(0,1)) for x in range(20)]
#list object is not callable

pi = m.pi
signal = []
carrier = []

##t = list(range(1,10000))
t = np.arange(10000)
fc = 0.01

for i in range(20):
    if a[i] == 0:
        sig =-np.ones(10001)
    else:
        sig = np.ones(10001)
    c = np.cos(2 *pi *fc *t)
    carrier = [carrier, c]
    signal = [signal, sig]

plt.plot(signal)
plt.title('Org. Bit Sequence')
```

Comment: You didn't declare nor import `rand`. Anyway, better would be `a = np.random.randint(0, 2, 20)`.  Also,  `sig = -np.ones(10001)` will be too long. Maybe `sig = -np.ones_like(t)` would just use the correct size. `carrier = [carrier, c]` creates a list of a list of a list of .... .  It would be better to append the lists, e.g. `carrier = np.hstack(carrier,  c)`?

Comment: what are the expected shape of `signal` and `carrier`?

Comment: @JohanC Sir, actually I declared random as rand. However, unintentionally I didn't add it into my question.. By trying your solution, it throws an error which: **TypeError: _vhstack_dispatcher() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given**.

Comment: Did you try `carrier = np.hstack([carrier, c])` ? Also, please edit your post and add the missing `rand`. Is there a reason you create the recursive `carrier` list without using it in the plot ?

Comment: @JohanC First of all thank you for your advise about editing my question. Just because I am very new at stackoverflow, I shared my question incompletely. After I tried `carrier = np.hstack([carrier, c])`, code neither throws error nor plots anything..

Comment: Did you try the same with `signal`? It looks like a very similar problem. Why don't you first test with much smaller arrays? Like `t = np.arange(10)`? And just repeating two times instead of 20? Once you get that working, you can start testing with larger numbers.

Comment: @JohanC If you mean `signal = np.hstack([signal, sig])` by **signal**, yes Sir I changed it too, after you advised it first time. By trying smaller integers code has worked and then by giving `t = np.range(10000)` at the end, code worked the way I expected (It gives some random rectangular pulses). I feel grateful  Sir, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Your code results in jagged arrays, because you keep assigning `signal = [signal, sig]` and `carrier = [carrier, c]`, which in both cases does not append to the existing list, but makes a level deeper list of two elements.

For example, after your code, `carrier` looks like:

```py
>>> carrier
[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[[],
                    array([1.        , 0.99802673, 0.9921147 , ..., 0.98228725, 0.9921147, 0.99802673])],
...
]

>>> len(carrier)
2

>>> len(carrier[0])
2

>>> len(carrier[0][0])
2

# etc.
```

Here is some code to produce two `(20, 10000)` arrays `signal` and `carrier`. I am not sure this is the shape you intend to obtain and what exactly you are trying to plot. Will adjust this answer if more details percolate through...

```py
n, m = 10_000, 20
fc = 0.01

sign = 2 * np.random.randint(0, 2, size=m) - 1
t = np.arange(n)
signal = sign[:, None] @ np.ones(n)[None, :]
carrier = np.ones((m, 1)) @ np.cos(2 * np.pi * fc * t)[None, :]
```

Now:

```py
>>> carrier.shape
(20, 10000)

>>> signal.shape
(20, 10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, `-np.ones()` wasn't working so I replaced it with `-1*np.ones()`. Secondly, by not using `append()` or a similar method you were saving a copy of the array into itself as a new element, like this:

```
>>> [[],np.ones()] #something like this first loop
>>> [[[],np.ones()],np.ones()] #second loop
>>> [[[[],np.ones()],np.ones()], np.ones()] #etc for twenty loops
```

This is what I did to get it working:

```
import numpy as np

import math as m

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import random as rand

a = [rand.randint(0,1) for x in range(20)]
#list object is not callable

pi = m.pi
signal = []
carrier = []

##t = list(range(1,10000))
t = np.arange(10000)
fc = 0.01

for i in range(20):
    if a[i] == 0:
        sig = -1*np.ones(10001)
    else:
        sig = np.ones(10001)
    c = np.cos(2 * pi * fc * t)
    carrier.append(c)
    signal.append(sig)


plt.plot(signal)
plt.title('Org. Bit Sequence')
plt.show()
```